# Trying to create an Object from class but don't know what to put for parameter

Tags: c#, camera, monogame

```
public Viewport view;

public Camera(Viewport newView)
        {
            view = newView;
            zoom = 2;
            rotation = 0;
        }
```

Sorry if this seems very basic but I can't figure it out for the life of me. I want to create an Object called 'camera' in my Game class, but I don't know what I need to input as the Viewport value.
Right now, in my Game class, I only have this:
`Camera camera = new Camera(//don't know what goes here);`

Comment: You should put `new ViewPort(x, y, width, height)` maybe. ? Doc here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/silverlight/dotnet-windows-silverlight/ff433830%28v%3dxnagamestudio.35%29

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor of the "Camera" class needs an "Viewport" object. Not more not less!

`Viewport vp = new Viewport();
 Camera cam = new Camera(vp);`

I don't know the Viewport class... Possible is also...

a)
`Viewport vp = new Viewport(param1, param2,...);`

b)
`Viewport vp = new Viewport() { Property1 = param1, Property2 = param2, ...};`

c)
Or do it instant `Camera cam = new Camera(new Viewport {Property1 = param1, Property2 = param2, ...}`

Comment: The viewport is already defined in MonoGame and is automatically set to the proper sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass it `graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport` as the parameter.

This assumes you are creating the instance of `Camera` in `Game1.cs`. Which you should be doing, since this effects the entire game.

Creating a new instance is redundant, and may not fit the target device.